# How do I use "slice_before" with initial_state in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

I saw Ruby 1.9 has a new enumerator, `slice_before`. The [API docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) are pretty cryptic.

In particular I'm baffled by the variation that takes an `initial_state` value.

For example, I want to split an array with numbers into sub-arrays whenever the progressive sum of the elements exceeds some value:

```
a = [1,2,0,1,2,3]
a.slice_before(0) do |elem, sum|
  sum += elem
  sum > 3
end.to_a
```

Expected output:

```
[[1,2,0], [1,2], [3]]
```

I'm thinking the sum is like a "carry" or "memo" as in `inject` but that doesn't seem to pan out.

The glitch in this code is a cryptic error:

```
TypeError: can't dup Fixnum
from (irb):43:in `each'
```

It looks like `slice_before` doesn't accept a `Fixnum` as initial value. Why? Ruby bug?.

I can work around this by keeping my own state variable, but it's not quite the beautiful Ruby semantic I was looking for.

```
sum = 0
a.slice_before do |elem|
  sum += elem
  sum > 3 && sum = 0
end.to_a

# => [[1, 2, 0], [1, 2], [3]]
```

So is `initial_state` usable for this purpose, or not? The examples in the docs seem to be mostly about text processing. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p194.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `initial_state` is typically a state hash that stores key-value pairs.

To write your code using a state hash:

```
a.slice_before(sum: 0) do |elem, state|
  state[:sum] += elem
  if state[:sum] > 3
    # Reset the sum, so we'll get more elements
    state[:sum] = 0  
  end
end.to_a
```

The `initial_state` must respond to the `#dup` method, because it is duplicated on each loop.

The reason `Fixnum` doesn't work is because it doesn't respond to `#dup`. A Fixnum wouldn't work because it can't keep track of state on each loop.

Comment: Very interesting. This wasn't intuitive. Thanks Joel. How did you find this out?

Comment: Could anyone explain the third line in this code example? why is the Boolean &&'d with (what appears to me like) an assignment?

Comment: Yes. I updated the code to make it clearer for you. In general "x && y" means boolean "and". In Ruby "x && y" can also mean "do x, and if the result is truthy, then do y". Similarly "x || y" can also mean "do x, and if the result is falsey, then do y".